# Copying files to RAM on Mac (Python)

Tags: python, linux, macos, unix, conv-neural-network

I am running some code from another user which builds a convnet. An early function attempts to copy the train and test images to `/dev/shm` by running:

```
import os
import time

paths = ["data/raw/images_train_rev1", "data/raw/images_test_rev1"]

for path in paths:
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join("/dev/shm",os.path.basename(path))):
        print "%s exists in /dev/shm, skipping." % path
        continue

    print "Copying %s to /dev/shm..." % path
    start_time = time.time()
    os.system("cp -R %s /dev/shm/" % path)
    print "  took %.2f seconds." % (time.time() - start_time)
```

I am getting the errors:

```
cp: /dev/shm: Permission denied
cp: data/raw/images_test_rev1: unable to copy extended attributes to 
/dev/shm: No such file or directory
```

Is there an alternative to `/dev/shm` that I can use on my Mac?

---

I have created a ramdisk in OSX using this information:

http://osxdaily.com/2007/03/23/create-a-ram-disk-in-mac-os-x/

Then: 
    ls -lah /dev/rdisk1
    crw-------  1 xxxx  staff    1,   4 27 May 16:26 /dev/rdisk1

However, when I try to write to it I get the error:

```
/rdisk1 is not a directory
took 0.78 seconds.
Copying data/raw/images_test_rev1 to /dev/rdisk1...
cp: /dev/rdisk1 is not a directory
took 0.02 seconds.
```

Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: anywhere which is mounted as `tmpfs`

Comment: Side note: `os.system()` has been superseded by functions from the `subprocess` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this utility https://gist.github.com/koshigoe/822455

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://gist.github.com/822455.git
cd 822455
chmod +x *
sudo ./mount-ram.sh /dev/shm 1024 
sudo chmod 777 /dev/shm
```

it will create a writable `/dev/shm` folder of 1G in RAM